# Add superclass to PsiClass

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

For an IntelliJ IDEA plugin, I want to create an inner class which extends from an already created class (an Android core class). What I want to achieve is:

```
class OuterClass { // This class is already created
    class InnerClass extends AnotherClass { // Class to create
        // to-do
    }
}
```

I can easily create the inner class, but I don't know how can I make the inner class to extend from another class (and what is more, there is no documentation on this :( ). This is my code:

```
PsiClass innerClass = psiElementFactory.createClassFromText(constructorAsString, outerPsiClass);
innerClass.setName("AwesomeName");
innerClass.getExtendsList().add(/* what to add here? */);
```

Comment: Have you tried PsiElementFactory#createClassReferenceElement? Or create the whole file from text at once, via PsiFileFactory?